# Get Labelled Files in GDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I wrote a code in Google Appscript to index all files in GDrive and try to identify if those files are labelled or not.

For summary, the Labels feature only available in GWorkspace business account and only the admin of the entreprise who have edit access of this feature.

I tried to use seacrhFiles(param) however the "Labels" isn't recognized by q string query Google, do we have another method to do it ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Features that are part of workspace business accounts. Are not part of the public Google drive api.

You can tell by looking at the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) object. It does not contain a field called label.

Your not going to find a method in the google drive api that will return a label on a file.

Even a [Google Document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document) resource object doesn't have it.

There may be a restricted api just for workspace users you would have to ask.  But its not something i have heard of.

Comment: Thank for the info. maybe i need to wait for a new improvement by google.

Answer (score 0):

### There will be a `labels API` that will allow you to to create, edit, apply, and remove labels programmatically

As of now, this API is still in development (beta stage), but you can get access to it if you contact drive-labels-feedback@google.com.

References:

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/9292382?hl=en&fl=1#zippy=%2Cis-it-possible-to-apply-labels-through-an-api
- https://issuetracker.google.com/167701931